# How can i get api response without refreshing the current page

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using the below API to get current chats from my database , the thing is the api works well, but issue is i have to refresh my page each time to see new chats, so i dont want that, any suggestions on how to get new chats without refresh, see my code below

```
getChatsList() {
    this.api.post_private('v1/chats/getById', { room_id: this.roomId 
      }).then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data && data.status && data.status === 200 && data.data.length) {
        this.messageList = data.data;
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the use case behind `i have to refresh my page each time`, is it time period based or on-demand if data changes?

Comment: no its not time based...the next user sends a response to database....but this user needs to pick it up..so i think its on demand if data changes

Comment: Then you need to look into adding websocket or similar messaging mechanism, where server can publish the update message, and client take listen to these messages to take action. UI side cannot do it itself, since UI has no direct connect to DB, to know something has changed in DB.

Comment: You either need to poll data (rxjs `interval` recommended) or connect with a websocket

Comment: any suggestions using rxjs intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getChatsList() {
this.api.post_private('v1/chats/getById', { room_id: this.roomId 
  }).then((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data && data.status && data.status === 200 && data.data.length) {
    this.messageList = data.data;
  }
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
setInterval(getChatsList, 1000);
```

**//Use this code, without reload current page.**